# High CPU due to SpEL in Message Handlers

Tags: spring-integration

We experience extremely high CPU (15 cores on 100%) when running high load on our application. The profiles shows that 20%+ is used by SpEL which is used mostly by the ServiceActivatingHandler. The application uses service activators to handle messages but never uses any SpEL.

There's about 12 ServiceActivators in a flow which are defined as follows:

`<service-activator ref="myService"/>`
or
`<service-activator ref="myService" method="addStuff"/>`

Most signatures are as follows:

`@ServiceActivator public Message<String> handle(Message<String>, @Header("header1") String header1, @Header("header2") String header2, @Header("header3") String header3)`

Profiling screenshot:
[image: Profiling screenshot]

How can this expression evaluation be avoided? Application runs on SprintBoot and SpringIntegration 4.3.x

Comment: The "Own time" of that call is `< 0.1` - you need to drill down into that `handleRequestMessage` to see where the time is actually being spent.

Comment: True but I don't have another screenshot at hand. Time is spent in OpNE and Ternary getInternalValue()

Comment: Can you show your configuration and the signature of `addStuff` and I'll see if I can reproduce. In the upcoming 5.0 release we don't use SpEL for most POJO method invocations.

Comment: I've added some details to the description. Can provide more details Friday. Any hints for testing focus are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting the headers is a bit expensive; it's a bit unusual to pass in the message and also have the framework extract headers. Since you have the whole message, you have access to the headers that way.

You can compile the SpEL, which is considerably faster; in my test it dropped from 8000ms (for 100,000 calls) to 137ms.

```
-Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED
```

However, this needs Spring Framework 4.3.7 or later ([this fix is needed](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15192)) or Spring Integration 4.3.8 or later ([which has this workaround](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4217))

In 5.0, we avoid SpEL if possible and the same test runs in about 400ms.

Comment: Accessing the headers using the `@Header` annotation seemed more elegant but can be changed quickly for the sake of performance. So the argument `-Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED` is still necessary for 4.3.8+ or is active by default?

Comment: You still need the system property to enable compilation. The problem was with the SpEL compiler not handling the ternary and Elvis operators. The compilation failed and SpEL dropped back to interpretation.

Comment: Upgraded to 4.3.9 and set the compiler flag, performance is above any expectations. Gary Russell, thank you very much, this is highly appreciated!

Comment: An interesting observation when using `-Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED`. When a handler throws and Exception, instead of going straight to the error channel, the handler is invoked a second time (this time interpreted and not compiled). If the Exception is thrown again, the error channel is invoked. Also, this happens only on the second invokation of the handler, most likley the first invokation is done in the interpreted mode. Therefore, we are now changing to IMMEDIATE

Comment: Ah - yes; an unfortunate side-effect of using SpEL to invoke POJOs. The expression doesn't know whether it was the compilation that caused the problem. Thanks for the update. I'll talk to the SpEL guru to see if there's a way around that.